# Is checkmytrip.com overloaded? Is there an alternative?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, planning, aircraft

I like to check my flight itenary on [checkmytrip.com](http://www.checkmytrip.com). The main reason is that while airline's webpages and check-in systems often don't provide some information out-of-the-box (for instance the aircraft type), checkmytrip seems to have the information ready all the time. (Yes, you can request the airline to tell you what type of aircraft will be used, but usually by a phone call or so, which is not convenient).

However, quite often it happens that the page simply doesn't load. Is the webpage overloaded? Is there any alternative that would provide the same information?

Comment: Any information other then aircraft type you're looking for?

Comment: @Karlson Well, nothing else specific. But I like the website, it lists a lot of supplementary information:  the weather conditions, links to weather forecasts, sometimes links to public transport directions etc.

Comment: If you are only interested in the aircraft type, please check Seat Guru (http://www.seatguru.com/) that also offers this kind of info. If not, please update your question to reflect what are you expecting.

Comment: @tohecz FlightAware lists equipment on flights day by day.  But equipment can change from day to day anyway.

Comment: @Ivan seatguru seems to provide the crucial information, thanks a lot. Still, I would prefer a site with more information in one place, but nevermind.

Answer (score 12):

Checkmytrip.com is only one of three public interfaces to a "[GDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Distribution_System)", the system that airlines use to track bookings.  Each GDS is independently operated and thus may not show bookings made with other systems (although they often show up anyway, it's all rather complicated).  The list (courtesy of [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Planning_your_flight)) is:

- **Abacus/Sabre**: http://www.virtuallythere.com/
- **Amadeus**: http://www.checkmytrip.com/
- **Apollo/Galileo/Worldspan**: http://www.viewtrip.com/

So if one of them is down, try the others, they might also work for you.