# Air France tickets not visible on checkmytrip (and alternatives)

Tags: online-resources, bookings, air-france

I recently bought (full paid) a flight ticket with Air France (from their official site) and I got my confirmation code (6 letters and digits).

Normally I use checkmytrip.com to check my flight details and save the page as PDF.

However this reservation is not available on checkmytrip (I get the message `The system is unable to retrieve this trip`) or alternative sites like the one I found in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23849/is-checkmytrip-com-overloaded-is-there-an-alternative)

Is Air France that uses a different booking system or there is another reason why I can't check my flight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am Product Manager on CheckMyTrip and the issue is easy to understand. Air France requested us to restrict the display of AF Bookings booked through Air France websites and offices into CheckMyTrip.
The way to avoid issues is :
- Forward to trips@checkmytrip.com jour AF Brookings then we will be legally authorized to do a snapshot of tour booking
- Or use the Air France mobile app/website